# Redirect page on vue.js from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

So, I have my Vue.js app running on `localhost:8080` and my Node.js server running on `localhost:3000`. I am implementing a reset password code, where I generate a token, and then send an email to the registered emailid. The email consists of a link that looks like : 
`localhost:3000/auth/resetpassword/40700dc92bb7be1ccf65fb120294f30a3be0e5b9`
Now by clicking on this link, I should be able to route that to a vue-router, but I do not know how that is to be done.

I also noticed that I will need a link that starts from `localhost:8080` to even access my vue.js app. So is there any way you can make the server render a vue.js page?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you having a single page application layout with hash in the url then you can redirect to the hash page by that url

Comment: No. My Vue-router has history on, so there's no #. Also its a multi-page application. So I kind of want it route to `localhost:8080/reset` @HitechHitesh

Comment: So you would be having that page name in the url.  So for development purpose you can add it hardcoded in the node js code

Comment: just make a route like `/auth/resetpassword/:key` and then you can access `key` through route props

Comment: @HitechHitesh How will it change in the production version?

Answer (score 0):

create a route `/auth/resetpassword/:id`

```
const NotFound = { template: '<p>Page not found</p>' }
const Home = { template: '<p>home page</p>' }
const Resetpassword = { template: '<p>Reset password</p>' }

const routes = {
  '/': Home,
  '/about': About,
  '/auth/resetpassword/:id' : Resetpassword
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentRoute: window.location.pathname
  },
  computed: {
    ViewComponent () {
      return routes[this.currentRoute] || NotFound
    }
  },
  render (h) { return h(this.ViewComponent) }
})
```

which can be accessed by `$route.params.id`

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to make the server render a vue.js page. It depend on what you need on real production app.

### Method 1: Serve your Vue app as static resources

You can just adjust your webpack bundle output path to your Node.js public directory. Serve them as static files(html document, css, js ...) in your Node.js server, just like any multi-page application you have. So you have to define every route rules the Vue app has to your node.js routes including `/auth/resetpassword/`. Also review all your static resource path. And you can access the vue app by `localhost:3000/auth/resetpassword/`.

If you use Vue CLI 3 and express:

**vue.config.js**

```js
// adjust bundle output path:
module.exports = {
  // ...
  outputDir: '../your-node-server/public/vue-app/',
  assetsDir: '../your-node-server/assets/',
  // ...
}

// and run `vue-cli-service build`
```

**/your-node-server/routes.js**

```
app.get('/auth/resetpassword/:token', function (req, res) {
  res.render('./public/vue-app/index.html');
});

// vue app may access some static assets e.g. http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

### Method 2: Separate `Vue app server` and `API server`

You can serve the vue app on the same way. Make the request url which has `/api` prefix to access localhost:3000, others request to access localhost:8080 by adjusting your nginx config providing reverse proxy.

something like:

**etc/nginx/conf.d**

```
// ...
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    // ...
}
```